# Problem with static variable

Tags: python, static

I'm trying to declare static variable and now my code is:

```
class StaticClass:
    varA = 'hello'

    @staticmethod
    def staticMethod():
        varA='bye'
```

Result of code below is hello. Why not 'bye' ?

```
StaticClass.staticMethod()

print StaticClass.varA
```

Comment: That looks like a Java pattern, not like Python.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to declare variable in one method , and have this variable accesable from other static methods in this class , and from other other class.

Comment: You don't need a method for that. This is Python, not Java.

Comment: @user278618: remember that this is Python, not Java, as @Daniel Roseman said. Maybe you've to re-design your classes before doing things like this. 
Have you considered using python properties?

Comment: "declare static variable" has no meaning in Python.  Nothing is "declared".  Why do you think you need  this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in `staticMethod()` assigns the string `bye` to the local variable `varA`, then returns, dropping the local variable.  An assignment inside a function always creates local variables in Python.  A `staticmethod` in Python has no means of accessing the class at all -- you need a `classmethod` for this purpose:

```
class StaticClass:
    var_a = 'hello'

    @classmethod
    def cls_method(cls):
        cls.var_a = 'bye'
```

Comment: output of StaticClass.cls_method()

print StaticClass.varA is 'hello'

Comment: @user278618: Are you sure?  Notice that I renamed `varA` to `var_a` because CamelCase is only used for class names in Python.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `varA` you define in `StaticClass.staticMethod()` is in the method's namespace, not in the class namespace, if you want to access the class' `varA` you should do something like:

```
StaticClass.varA = 'bye'
```

By the way, you don't need to create a staticmethod to do this.